# C# ASP.NET MVC - Model gets nulled on POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now and I can't find any solution on that solves it for me.

I'm trying to add a string to my model in a view, however when the model gets returned to my HttpPost everything is null except for the string that I'm trying to fill

My model looks like this

```
namespace WhatsUp.Models {
    public class ChatModel
    {
        public Account user { get; set; }
        public Contact contact { get; set; }
        public Chat chatA { get; set; }
        public Chat chatB { get; set; }
        public string newMessage { get; set; }

        public ChatModel() { }

        public ChatModel(Account user, Contact contact, Chat chatA, Chat chatB)
        {
            this.user = user;
            this.contact = contact;
            this.chatA = chatA;
            this.chatB = chatB;

        }
    }
}
```

My controller looks like this

```
namespace WhatsUp.Controllers
{
    public class ChatsController : Controller
    {
        IMessageRepository repository = new DbMessageRepository();
        IContactRepository contactRepository = new DbContactRepository();
        IAccountRepository accountRepository = new DbAccountRepository();
        IChatRepository chatRepository = new DbChatRepository();

        // GET: Chats
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Chat(int contactId)
        {

            Account user = accountRepository.GetAccount(User.Identity.Name);
            Contact contact = contactRepository.GetContact(contactId);
            Chat chatA = chatRepository.GetChat(user.id, contact.accountId ?? default(int));
            if(chatA == null)
            {
                chatRepository.CreateChat(user.id, contact.accountId ?? default(int));
            }
            Chat chatB = chatRepository.GetChat(contact.accountId ?? default(int), user.id);
            if(chatB == null)
            {
                chatRepository.GetChat(user.id, contact.accountId ?? default (int));
            }
            ChatModel chatModel = new ChatModel(user, contact, chatA, chatB);

            return View(chatModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Chat(ChatModel chatModel)
        {
            repository.SendMessage(new Message(0, chatModel.newMessage, chatModel.chatA.Id));
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View(chatModel);
        }


    }
}
```

And my view

```
@using WhatsUp.Models
@model ChatModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Chat";
}

<h2>Chat with @Model.contact.name</h2>

<div id="chatWindow" style="overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden; height:500px;">    

    <script>
    var element = document.getElementById('chatWindow');
    element.scrollTop = element.offsetHeight
    </script>
</div>


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.newMessage, new { @class = "form-control"})
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary" />
    }
```

Comment: First create a ViewModel that will contain your message and the chat ids.
Make the ids as a hidden field in your view. 
In your POST action make sure to get each chat via their id before sending the message.

Comment: @Broodstok Your `Form` contains only a `TextBox` with name `newMessage`. On form Post, Contents of your text box will be the model object newMessage. The reason rest are empty because they are not contained in the form.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Thanks a lot! That worked.

Comment: @Broodstok I posted it as an answer. You can accept it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use a ViewModel for that kind of things. Follow this steps:

- First, create a `ViewModel` that will contain your message and the chat ids.
- Second, ake the `id`s as a hidden field in your view.
- Last thing is, in your POST action, to make sure to get each `Chat` instance via their `id` before sending the message.